# Reformat Code: consistency for double and single quotes?

Tags: phpstorm

I use PhpStorm both at work and privately. The version at work gives a "warning" whenever I use double quotes instead of single quotes to ensure consistency, but this doesn't seem to be a default option, as it doesn't do that in my private version.

How can I set it up so it gives a warning whenever I use double quotes (I prefer single quotes)? Ideally, it would be cool if "Reformat Code" would do that automatically, but I don't mind doing it myself if it's at least highlighted. Is there a setting for it?

Comment: What language? PHP? AFAIK formatter does not touch quotes, you can only fix it manually (one by one or in bulk) as that is an Inspection (from 3rd party plugin AFAIK) and not a code style option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you actually refer to an inspection rather than any Reformat Code option:

[image: Safely use single quotes instead]

You can normally find the inspection if you type some keywords from the description in the *Settings* search box and check the appropriate language node:

[image: Find inspection]

As shown in the dialogue, mine is coming from a [third-party plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7622-php-inspections-ea-extended-).